# Is azure SQL database only allowed android 11 to access?

Tags: android, azure-sql-database

Recently I formed an android application and installed on my phone which is of version 11. Everything just went smoothly. But then, when my friend tried on her phone of version 8, she cannot connect to the azure SQL database. Then I tried to give more people to try. Only Android 11 is able to access azure SQL database. I have set the firewall rule of azure SQL server to accept all IP address. I think it is a problem about SSL Connection. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying different `SSL/TLS levels` like

```
sslProtocol=TLSv1.2
```

The Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server supports setting the SSL protocol via the connection string.

```
 String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;userName=sa;password=PASSW0RD;database=master;sslProtocol=TLS";

 SQLServerConnection con = (SQLServerStatement) DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
```

Another way to set the default label is using a SQLServerDataSource object.

```
SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
ds.setUser("sa");
ds.setPassword("PASSWORD");
ds.setServerName("localhost");
ds.setPortNumber(1433);
ds.setDatabaseName("master");
ds.setSSLProtocol("TLS");
SQLServerConnection con = (SQLServerConnection) ds.getConnection();
```

Refer – [JDBC Connection issue to Azure SQL Database](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/506682/jdbc-connection-issue-to-azure-sql-database.html)